# trigger a href sip/tel link on button click jquery

Tags: triggers, onclick, href, sip, jquery-click-event

I'm trying to **trigger a click event** that will open my *href sip/tel link* when **user clicks the button**, but it **doesn't trigger the click event** after the button has been pressed.

jquery code:

```
$('#next_button').click(function() {
       var num = $(this).val();
       $('#call-num'+num).trigger('click');
       alert(num);
});
```

href code:

```
<a href="tel:001(999) 888-3333" id="call-num1">(999) 888-3333</a>
<button id="next_button" value="1">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#next_button').on('click', function() {
      var num = $(this).val();
      var call = $('#call-num'+num).attr('href');
      location.href = call;
      alert(call);
});
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: that is the complete answer to my question